# Cкрыть некоторые компоненты на tabsheet

Tags: delphi

Подскажите, как скрыть некоторые компоненты на tabsheet 
[image: Кредитовая][image: дебетовая]
На дебетовой скрыть источники дохода, вроде скрыл а на кредитовой их показать но скрыть платежи по службе, там не получилось!

Вот код:

```
procedure TfrmPayment.FormShow(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if (cxPageControl1.ActivePageIndex = 0) then
    begin
     lblDoxod.Visible := False;
      cbDoxod.Visible := False;
      lbl8.Visible := True;
      cbDep.Visible := True;
    end;
  if (cxPageControl1.ActivePageIndex = 1) then
    begin
      lblDoxod.Visible := True;
      cbDoxod.Visible := True;
      lbl8.Visible := False;
      cbDep.Visible := False;
    end;
end;
```

Comment: дак вы попробуйте код писать не в `formShow` а что-то вроде `tabChange`

Comment: и рассмотрите возможность завести тип данных, а-ля `TTabType = (ttCredit, ttDebet)`, потом взять индекс текущего таба, привети его к этому типу, `ctt := TTabType(.. .activePageIndex)`, и скрывать/показывать элементы в виде `control.visible := ctt = ttCredit`, или там `c.visible := ctt in [ttCredit, ttDebet]`, это куда нагляднее и читабельнее чем куча ифоф. С индексами конечно такое не очень хорошо делать, для подобных дел обычно используют свойство `tag`

Answer (score 1):

Вы записали код скрытия элементов не в том обработчике. Событие [TForm.OnShow](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Rio/en/Vcl.Forms.TForm.OnShow) срабатывает при показе формы, и если у вас это главная форма, то оно происходит только один раз - при запуске программы.

То что вам нужно - событие [TPageControl.OnChange](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Rio/en/Vcl.ComCtrls.TCustomTabControl.OnChange), которое происходит всякий раз, когда вы переключаетесь между табами. Перенесите свой код в этот обработчик, и всё будет работать как надо.

Comment: К сожалению, всё равно не работает((

Comment: @user284221 Ищите ошибку у себя и воспользуйтесь дебагером. Для начала, поставьте брекпоинт и убедитесь, что срабатывает событие `OnChange`.

Comment: Не принципиально, у человека PageControl, там на каждом TabSheet свои элементы, их можно и при старте все прекрасно настроить... Вот если бы это был TabControl, тогда другое дело. Другой вопрос, что он меняет видимость элементов вовсе не на TabSheet, как стоит в вопросе, или не видит, что на разных TabSheet они у него должны быть разные

Comment: @Isaev С одной стороны - согласен, но с другой стороны - если на каждом табе свои элементы и они должны быть невидимы, то зачем они вообще там?

Comment: это вопрос к автору) я вижу только то, что он привёл

Answer (score 0):

Всем спасибо, все работает)

При open:

```
cxPageControl1.ActivePageIndex := 0;
cbDoxod.Visible := False;
lblDoxod.Visible := False;
cbDep.Visible := True;
lbl8.Visible := True;
```

При PageChanging:

```
if (cxPageControl1.ActivePageIndex = 1) then
begin
  lblDoxod.Visible := False;
  cbDoxod.Visible := False;
  lbl8.Visible := True;
  cbDep.Visible := True;
end
else
begin
  lblDoxod.Visible := True;
  cbDoxod.Visible := True;
  lblDoxod.Top := 51;
  cbDoxod.Top := 48;
  lbl8.Visible := False;
  cbDep.Visible := False;
end;
```

Comment: А почему вы решили использовать событие `OnChanging`, а не `OnChange`, как я советовал?

Comment: @zed дак ткнул в первое похожее видимо :) зы: почему бы исходные значения не задать в конструкторе форм, зачем их писать в onShow ?